# Is Rosa Balladares mother of all these children?

Tags: 20th-century, vital-records, familysearch.org, nicaragua

I am looking for the children of Rosa Balladares, born in Nicaragua. I found the corresponding records on FamilySearch.

When I was able to access the mentioned records some months ago, I was asking myself, whether anyone would guess whether the Rosa mentioned in all this records is the mother of all listed children? Even more puzzling is why would only for death certificate of Olga be a husband, Carlos Castros, be indicated, while not in the others?, see https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FSDX-298 .

The corresponding records are:

- Jose: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS86-4S3
- Graciela: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS8D-P9G
- Olga: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS86-R4S
- Mercedes: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS8X-8Y4
- Carlos: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS8K-CNP
- Maria: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS8T-S4T
- Carlos II: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS8Y-QYC
- Josefa: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FSD7-BXS
- Maria II: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FSXD-MD9

**Addendum:**

Too all `LDS` members: I pasted a lookup inquiry in the `root` chat of `genealogy.stackexchange` [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) as suggested by Harry Vervet. Please, if you have the extra minutes, would you be so kind as to provide the above mentioned records to me in addition to this record of a relevant parent, Zoila: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FS86-B66 ?

**Edit:**
Today (June 3, 2017), I discovered that all links above are available for me (non-LDS account). I just downloaded all records.

Comment: Hi Til – lookup requests are not a good fit for this site, because there is no answer to the question. If it is not contravening any terms of service to provide lookups, then you are fine to ask over in chat if anyone can provide that lookup. If you can modify this question to just the first part (Is Rosa Balladares the mother of all this children?) then that would be fine. I would add that several of the linked record images can be viewed on Ancestry – try your local library if you don't have personal access.

Comment: I just edited my question. Thank you for your advice, Harry!

Comment: I apologize for making an example of you, but I've used your question as an inspiration for a self-answered question. If you have comments about other things to add, I'd appreciate it. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12994/1006

Comment: What message do you see when you try to use the links?  Did my minor edit change the meaning of your question -- if so, please revert it.

Comment: Hi Jan, it is fine for me to be used as an example. :) Before posting this question, I was wondering why there no other question yet of this kind on `genealogy.stackexchange`. The message I see is `This image is available:
When using the site at a family history center.
To signed-in members of supporting organizations.` This rather cryptic message means that only members of the church would get access. The interesting thing is that the choice to block one record or the other seems to be erratic and changes over time. Even within a collection, there are differences (s. example above)

Comment: Hi Til, at this point it would be very helpful if you could include the basic information about each child in the question (i.e. date and place of birth, listed parents names, etc). It's quite time consuming to go through all the links which don't appear to be in any real order currently. Someone's more likely to answer if they can wade through the information quickly. In other words, I think the first step here is organizing the information, otherwise if you're anything like me you'll very quickly get befuddled.

Comment: @TilHund quick note that the message about using a family history center applies/shows up to members too. Some sources are only accessible at family history centers, which anyone can visit provided they are open.